# Embedding Larger token text (> 3k) with Neo4j apoc.ml.vertexai.embedding

Tags: neo4j, large-language-model, apoc-extended

The documentation of Neo4j says, i can set embedding as node property. All works fine when the embedding text is < 3k limit of as i can embed all text in one go and set as Neo4j node property.

Not sure, how the same can be be done, If i have to split the embedding text(because of token limit) and then generate multiple list of embedded values?

Any examples or pointers, will be of greathelp.

Thanks,